# How to create a C# DLL for Xamarin.Android from C++

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.android, swig

I have an iPad application written in C# using Xamarin.IOS, that uses some C++ code which has been built into a C# DLL following the instructions [here](http://blog.reblochon.org/2013/01/c-bindings-for-monotouch-using-swig.html).

I am now wanting to add an Android version of my application, so I need to build a version of this DLL that will be compatible.

For the Xamarin.IOS version, the process is essentially:

1. The C++ code is compiled with XCode to make a lib.a file
2. SWIG is used to generate some C# interface files from the C++ header files
3. XCode builds a libWrapper.a file from one of the files SWIG generates
4. SMCS (seems to be a Xamarin tool command line tool) combines the lib.a, libWrapper.a and an AssemblyInfo.cs file into a C# dll, which can be added as a reference to the iPad project.

Using the DLL already generated in the Xamarin.Android project doesn't work (it gives a P/Invoke EntryPointNotFound error), presumably because it is built for iOS devices (i386, arm7 and arm7s) and it needs to be built differently for Android?

I think I need to use the Android NDK to compile the C++ (as opposed to XCode), but what would that produce and how do I convert it into a C# DLL in order to add it to my Xamarin.Android project?

Answer (score 0):

Android NDK will produce a .so file. You can use the same PInvoke methods as in your iOS wrapper. I have used SWIG with Android before so there should not be any difference since it's a C interface.

Add the .so file to a library project and set it to build as EmbeddedNativeLibrary.

http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/advanced_topics/using_native_libraries/